# how to get MapView API in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview

how to get MapView API in android?

thanks

Comment: Please, explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve. Your question is not really well phrased. What do you mean by how do I get MAPView API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is actually written in Android documentation: [Hello, MapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

Comment: but my project shows an error when i extending MapActivity Class.. why?

Answer (score 3):

for windows

step1: start --> run-->

type

C:\Documents and Settings\ashish\.android

***hear you should be pass your current user***
and find debug.keystore

[image: description]

now get the path of debug.keystore

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ashish\.android\debug.keystore
```

now  the command for getting MD5

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

so now we pass the path of dedug.keystore

the full command is

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\ashish\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

step 2: start--> run-->

type cmd and change directory to **android sdk's platform-tools** and past the following command
[image]
press enter

[image]

now  you are getting MD5 now how to use it.....
now Go to https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

[image]

after that press button It will give you map api

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step-by-step description on how to enable MapView API in your android application:

[Maps External Library](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html)

You will need to put a reference to your application manifest:

[Referencing the Maps Library from the Application's Manifest File](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#useslibrary)