# Generating Google map Release API Key

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

My app uses Google Maps, I signed up for a Google Maps key to debug, it worked. But now, I need a Google Maps key in release mode, before publishing. How can I get it?

Comment: did you sign your application with a certificate? The key you get for release has to be based off that cert.  Check out this article, the very last statement: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/#apikey

Comment: Please have a look my answer  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281317/how-to-get-mapview-api-in-android/10411290#10411290](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281317/how-to-get-mapview-api-in-android/10411290#10411290)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211394/i-tell-you-how-to-generate-api-key-for-your-eclipse

Comment: Here is a good post about generating Debug Key and Release Key: http://chocotech.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-debug-key-and-release-key-for.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to :

1. Create your own signing key that you will use for publishing, using Keytool : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert
2. Get the MD5 fingerprint of your newly generated key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getfingerprint
3. Submit the signature to this link to get your Google Maps key : https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup?hl=fr
4. Export your application with your newly created key, in Eclipse : right click on your projet -> Android Tools -> Export signed application package.

Be careful to keep your certificate in a safe place, because you will need it if you want to publish an update of your app on Google Play.

EDIT :

For the Google Maps Android V2, the signing is a little different. You will need to get the SHA-1 signature and provide the package name of your application as well. A Google APi account is moreover needed. All info are given on this page : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: I have a key and tried to develop a app but no success, nothing happens when i open the app, no location is loaded (no default location) not in my emulator and not in my phone

Answer (score 1):

Before **publishing application** into play store you have to follow some step to create `release key.`

**Step 1:**
First find your key store location.
Ex.  D:\Harshid\testKeystore

**Step 2:**
Run this command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore D:\Harshid\ testKeystore -alias D:\Harshid\ testKeystore
```

please used **fully qualified name of keystore.**

**Step 3:**
Copy SHA1

**Step 4:**
Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) `google map api console.`

Answer (score 0):

> i hope u know that The Android build process signs your application
>   differently depending on  which build mode you use to build your
>   application. There are two build modes: **debug mode and release mode**.
>   You use debug mode when you are developing and testing your
>   application.

***The debug signing process happens automatically when you run or debug your application using Eclipse with the ADT plugin***

- For Release mode-

**if you are using Eclipse with the ADT plugin**, you can use the Export Wizard to export a signed APK (and even create a new keystore, if necessary). The Export Wizard performs all the interaction with the Keytool and Jarsigner for you, which allows you to sign the package using a GUI instead of performing the manual procedures to compile, sign, and align, as discussed above. Once the wizard has compiled and signed your package, it will also perfom package alignment with zipalign. Because the Export Wizard uses both Keytool and Jarsigner, you should ensure that they are accessible on your computer, as described above in the [Basic Setup for Signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#setup).

- To create a signed and aligned APK in Eclipse:
- Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File > Export.
        Open the Android folder, select Export Android Application, and click Next.
- The Export Android Application wizard now starts, which will guide
  you through the process of signing your application, including
  steps for selecting the private key with which to sign the APK (or
  creating a new keystore and private key).
- Complete the Export Wizard and your application will be compiled,
  signed, aligned, and ready for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\admin\.android>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\U
sers\admin\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
androiddebugkey, Oct 14, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 67:0D:D0:72:C6:4C:C0:5B:68:AD:B5:BC:ED:AB:BE:DF



2012

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>cd .android

C:\Users\admin\.android>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\U
sers\admin\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
androiddebugkey, Jan 9, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): DC:31:3D:50:D1:74:27:DD:DE:7C:4D:D3:9E:FC:7E:4B

C:\Users\admin\.android>




10-March 2012

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:apiKey="0ogz8aFVENHYdrrUL1WWWZIcv06YYgtRT7zL-vA"
                 />



C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -list -keystore "C:\Users\adm
n\izeeka.keystore"
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

abc, Apr 5, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): A9:BA:68:1F:6B:30:8D:78:36:3F:AE:5F:BA:35:7A:EE



C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -list -keystore "C:\Users\admi
n\.android\edtechconference.keystore"
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

abc, Sep 6, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 8A:41:56:2F:64:80:6A:5C:5C:90:AF:E2:94:C4:D8:0A

Apikey:0ogz8aFVENHZSMYjvPgixpaCWH21Z2zEulRruDA




C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -list -keystore "D:\google"
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

a, Jul 9, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 74:0F:CA:7C:34:44:34:3E:52:74:EE:41:F8:FC:68:44

//SHA--1
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -exportcert -alias androiddebu
gkey -keystore "C:\Users\admin\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
Enter keystore password:
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Jul 17, 2012
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 5004ffd3
Valid from: Tue Jul 17 11:31:55 IST 2012 until: Thu Jul 10 11:31:55 IST 2042
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  09:37:6A:CE:A7:14:17:B5:0E:24:05:BD:A8:BA:29:63
         SHA1: 7A:EB:A6:D4:DA:04:7B:E6:09:C5:7F:C8:BA:2C:82:54:C7:99:1E:AF
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3







_Mapapikey-----------------19/7/2013


C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -
keystore "C:\Users\admin\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass an
droid
androiddebugkey, Jul 17, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 09:37:6A:CE:A7:14:17:B5:0E:24:05:BD:A8:BA:29:63
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug key will not work for the release build. Pls go through the info mentioned about generating key in this [official page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=fr#step_1_download_android_studio). Moreover, you can add the SHA1 for both your release and debug build, if you want to use a single key for both debugging and release purposes.

Answer (score -2):

```
If you cannot generate api key then you can use my key as given define.
1]key=AIzaSyCeBdq7rr-R7w7vZCXscLWgEDb3oO9CUhw
2]key=AIzaSyCc7FZQ6jG2VcxnxbMNdkPFFzrUsJxq-ys
3]key=AIzaSyBQuNDY3fycSayPzaE7lzMDxZqMSOKF8AA
4]key=AIzaSyDJ7rKNS4BjfM8qfsY6oJzsYvXGkQV8hTo

5]key=AIzaSyDFasJ3EgYe3HCfjyLLVM1DMaQjD7cgWpk&v=3.exp&libraries=places
    --This is special for version 3--

If above define all key are working. Hope this key is useful for you
```