# Android google maps release API key

Tags: android, google-maps

Can somebody explain me how to generate Google Api release key.
Google maps works perfectly on Virtual Device Manager, but on the phone not.

Comment: This is good explenation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386770/google-map-release-api-key-how-generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a new key for the release build. Pls go through the info mentioned in this [official page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=fr#step_1_download_android_studio). Moreover, you can add the SHA1 for both your release and debug build, if you want to use a single key for both debugging and release purposes.