# Google map doesn't work on app from google play

Tags: android, dictionary, api-key

i know this was asked before but i think i have little different situation.

I have two keys for mapview, debug and production. As far as I know, to create map key suitable for google play, you first create a keystore from eclipse(using create new keystore option in export signed app dialog), extract fingerprint and generate api key from google's api signup page.

Then you can use this key to export signed app and install it on device using adb utility and map will work, whereas usign debug won't. Right?

So far it's good. Map works if I install it using adb or device's package manager. But it won't work if I put app on google play and then install from it. It is the same situation as would be if I work with debug key: IOException with message: server returned: 3.

Maybe the important bits. An play account was registered with different email(which i do not posses) as was used when generating "production" map api key. Could this be the problem?

**Edit**:
Some clarification. I am the second delevoper on the app. The first one used different keystore and different api key which he used to sign apllication for submiting it on Play. After I took over the project, i created a new keystore and used its fingerprint to acquire api key. I used this key to create signed packages which if I install shows map normaly, as it should.

Now, I created signed package (using the key generated from keystore) and install it(adb) and I can see the map normally(which wouldn't if I would be using debug key). But when I upload the update of app on play and install it from there, the map breaks.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386770/google-map-release-api-key-how-generate there are many more with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating fingerprint, be sure to use the same keystore which you have created for the project to be uploaded.

Comment: Yep, the Google Maps API Key must be the one generated from the release keystore.

Comment: Is the release keystore, the which you can create with Eclipse "Export signed application package" and choose "Create new keystore" on the second step?

Comment: yes its the same keystore. When you generate fingerprint, do remember to give path of this keystore instead of the dafault keystore in android.

Comment: After reading your edit, you need to generate map key with the same keystore that you generated earlier(before uploading it to google play)

Comment: You mean, with the keystore of the previous developer? Is there any other way?

Comment: yes....you have to use the same keystore. You cannot sign two versions with different keys.

Comment: And in case, that I can't get his keystore. What are my options?

Comment: Sorry to say but you can't do anything about it. If you have uploaded new version of app with different signing key and dint faced any error then also your application in the market will still remain with the old version even after update.