# Google Maps Api Key not valid after to sign the app?

Tags: android, google-maps, key, publish

Yesterday I signed my app in Google Play. My app contains Google Maps. Now the Api Key (for debug) not works.

Is neccesary to change the Api Key when you publish an app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to get release api key based on release SHA1 (it's different than deug one)

Comment: Yes, I have published my app with 2 api keys (debug and google play). But now, I want to use the debug api key but it not works...

Comment: You must use debug key with debug version of application and release key with release version of application. Be sure you didn't mix it

Comment: But I only have one version of app

Comment: When you debug it's one version, when you export it for publishing it's other version although it is same application. But their SHA1 is different so you need to get another key. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386770/google-map-release-api-key-how-generate