# How to solve the obtaining a key for google maps in the release version?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-studio

Made an application using a plain maps Google, generally made ​​key for debug version everything works, but to release version can not do anything SEARCH.Tell me please how to make a key for Google Maps on the platform Android, only for the release version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389546/3168859)

It says

You need to :

1. Create your own signing key that you will use for publishing, using
   Keytool :
   http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert
2. Get the MD5 fingerprint of your newly generated key :
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getfingerprint
3. Submit the signature to this link to get your Google Maps key :
   https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup?hl=fr
4. Export your application with your newly created key, in Eclipse :
   right click on your projet -> Android Tools -> Export signed
   application package.

Be careful to keep your certificate in a safe place, because you will need it if you want to publish an update of your app on Google Play.

EDIT :

For the Google Maps Android V2, the signing is a little different. You will need to get the SHA-1 signature and provide the package name of your application as well. A Google APi account is moreover needed. All info are given on this page : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key