# Google maps in an android app

Tags: android, google-maps

Im trying to add google map into my app.
Ive added the API key into the manifests

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAoWtqYmkOh4******8sNehbI8APKNnI08" />
```

and also the premissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

when i run the app on my phone in debug mode (and MTP mode)
the map is shown..
but when i generate the apk file and install it manually, the map doesnt show.

what is the problem?

Comment: You need to add the release key on google console. I believe

Comment: You can either build your release apk with a release key, or you can build a debug apk and use your current key. Obviously it depends on where you are at in your application building process.

Comment: did you get a release key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add the release key  (so you will have two keys one for debug and the other for relase)

[image: gMaps key]

the answer is here
[Generating Google map Release API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386770/generating-google-map-release-api-key)

ok here is what that xml contains

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">AIzaSyB_______THE_KEY______corZYhm_pmI</string>

</resources>
```

and in the manifest file add this in

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

open your app in explorer and create a release folder and put your xml containing the release key here app\src\release\res\values

and the xml containing the debug key here app\src\debug\res\values

[image: capture]

Comment: what should i write inside this file?

Comment: is this your release key ...did you put it into the release folder ?

Comment: for me i have two xml file with the same name "google_maps_api" and the same text (only the key is deffirent) ..one is in the debug directory .. the other as you can see is in the release directoy

Comment: I dont have those folders.. this is my project: [link]http://postimg.org/image/5ujgi6xnv/)

Comment: open your app in explorer

Comment: the (Debug) in your picture means that that xml is in the debug folder ... right click on your app and select open in browser .. and create the folders that are messing