# Unsigned apk vs signed apk Google Map not showing

Tags: android, google-play, apk, signed-apk

I have done an Android app which takes the data from a server database.
If I install it from an USB installation or installing an unsigned apk everything works properly but, if I install it from a signed apk (or downloading it from PlayStore) the maps activity does not work.

Once I have installed it, my app does a request to an API in order to take the data in its database an fill the app's db so I can show the data from the app db.

I know it is getting the data since I can see everything allright but maps Activity, which looks like following:

USB/Unsigned apk:
[image: USB/Unsigned apk:]

Signed apk:
[image: Signed apk:]

Does anyone know if there is any diferent between these two apks that may be causing this unexpected behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your hash in Google Developer Console. You need to add hash for release key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a Release key with your keystore file and password for `Signed` Apk

Then u have to add the key in developer console

**Step 1**

in command prompt:

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore /home/rafsan/Desktop/Android/Projects/TestApp/keystore.jks -alias test -storepass password -keypass password
```

where

`/home/rafsan/Desktop/Android/Projects/TestApp/keystore.jks` is the path where your `keystore` file for the signed apk is present

`test` is the key `alias` name used while genrating the signed key store

and `password` is the `password` used while signing the apk

**Step 2**

Go to [Developer console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

and add the release key with package

```
A3:33:EA:3D:5E:....................85;com.example.package_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you generate release certificate ? Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389546/5684110).I think this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Maps API key with your debug certificate but not with your release one.

Follow the steps here and get a new key

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/